# Permanent table, temp tables or php session?

Tags: sql, php, temp-tables

My web app offers personalized recommendations. When a user starting to use it, about 1000+ rows are being inserted to one big recommendation table, correlating with other tables in the database. Every item the user votes for affects all of those 1000+ rows.

Since the recommendation info is only useful during the session, and since the recommendation table is getting huge, we'd like to switch to a more appropiate method. There's the possibility of deleting the relevant rows as soon as the user session is over. I guess PHP session array or temp tables are better for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: consider redesigning your data structure, I think it is not optimal.
Store a user's recommendation in a table user-recommendeditem-score: I don't see any need for a temp table or anything else.
Otherwise, you could start using sessions, but you should encapsulate the code carefully, making it easy to change if/when this solution is no more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

One temp table per session will lead to catalog pollution, so not really recommended.

Have you considered actually keeping the data, so as periodically mine it to improve the suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't it cause a huge, slow table? 1000 rows times every user that has ever used the site? I do save users' actual choices.

Comment: I also wonder about what is the best method preformance-wise. is one big table the way to go?

Comment: Well, it's up to you to identify which data to keep and how to best store it... To be honest, it sounds a bit crazy to have 1k+ writes per session. So sessions seem right, if only to avoid re-querying the data on each page view. :-) Nonetheless, there has to be something of interest in there that you may want to store (perhaps in some aggregated format).

Comment: Do you think php session will be better than deleting the rows from the big table?

Comment: You'd want to test, but I suspect you'll get less overhead by serializing/unserializing to a file that you will from inserting/selecting/deleting to an indexed table.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the method is flawed - 1000+ recommendations per user? How many of them do they ever **look** at? If you don't know the answer to that question - then you need to spend some time thinking about why you don't know the answer.

> Every item the user votes for affects all of those 1000+ rows

Are you sure your data is properly normalised?

But leaving that aside for the moment. The right place to generate / store that is in the database - a relational database is explicitly designed, and a lot more efficient about generating and maintaining tabular sets of data then a conventional programming language.

Comment: thing is, if you want to get the best recommendation out of all the possible items, you have to rate all of them according to the uses'r choices, and the pick the top items